# Converting MySQL Charset in Database (Also Mysqli Charset Related)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, utf-8, character-encoding

Unfortunately all my databases (and Collations) are `utf8_general_ci` and I just recently learn it is better to use `utf8_unicode_ci` as it supports more Unicode characters accurately.

Will there be any issues if I use phpMyAdmin to change the Collations and database Table Charsets through their menus?

Also as I didn't know the importance of charsets, I have not been setting my MySQLi charsets for my database connection in PHP. Should I go through and do `mysqli->set_charset("utf8")` for all my connections? It is currently set as "latin1" by default. I assume this could be an issue as as I am storing as UTF8 but accepting latin1? (I am however declaring UTF8 on my html pages with

```
 meta charset="utf-8"
```

I also read it might be better to go straight to utf8mb4? Again, would I have any issues changing that with phpMyAdmin and is it worth it? If I do go `utf8mb4` do I have to do `mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4')` ?

Thanks! I really should of done this to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`CHARACTER SET` is the *encoding* of the bytes.  `COLLATION` is how characters are compared (for `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`).

You cannot trivially change either of those after the table is built.  Instead you need to do some form of `ALTER`, probably `ALTER ... CONVERT TO ...`.

The *character set* `utf8mb4` has the advantage of handling all of Chinese (utf8 is missing some characters) and Emoji (the newer smileys).

The *collation* `utf8_unicode_520_ci` (or `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` for character set utf8mb4) is based on a newer Unicode standard, so it is arguably the 'best' available in MySQL.

So, yes,

1. `ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATION utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;`
2. `mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');` right after connecting.
3. In HTML, have `<meta charset=UTF-8>`

There is a chance that the `CONVERT TO` will come across "duplicate keys", since the *_unicode_* collations work differently than *_general_ci.  That won't happen for English, and won't happen for most of Europe.  Two exceptions come to mind: the German `ß` in some `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY` column, and any accented letters that are 'composed' of a 'non-spacing' accent together with a letter.  (The latter is very rare.)